# Navigation drawer icon fill the transparent part of the icon with specific color

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Currently i have this kind of icon in my navigation drawer

[image]

what i want to do is to put color in the transparent part of the icon.

This is the current look of my navigation drawer:

[image]

The color is outside of the transparent part of the image which is wrong.

here is my current code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/main_activity_navigationdrawer_layout"
       app:itemIconTint="@color/aub_red"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_activity_menu" />
```

Comment: Your icon has the white background. Please use the background transperent in icon

Comment: @JaiminThakkar can you elaborate? i'm sorry.

Comment: Make your icon transparent background with fill of white color.. Please compare the maps icon of your layout.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: you need to change in design of icon.Maybe designer will help you in that

Comment: No, i need to fill a color in the transparent part. the icon is fine

Comment: Right now its fitting the color in transparent part.. Red color which you have mentioned in layout file